# my links are not working in my react router app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

My links in the following code are not working. I'm a beginner and I'm not sure on where the issue is.
Do you have any tips on how to debug that?

Thank you,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import {fetchItems} from './actions/items';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home.js'
import Additem from './components/Additem'
import Mybag from './components/Mybag.js'
import About from './components/About.js'
import ItemShow from './components/ItemShow.js'
import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar.js'

class App extends Component {


  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchItems();
  }

  render() {
    console.log("itemList: ", itemList)
    const itemList = this.props.items
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <NavigationBar />
        <React.Fragment>
          <Route exact path='/' render={routerProps => <Home {...routerProps} items={itemList}/>} />
          <Route exact path={`/items/:itemID`} component={ItemShow} />
          <Route exact path="/my_bag" component={Mybag} />
          <Route exact path="/add_item" component={Additem} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      items: state.items
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      fetchItems: (items) => dispatch(fetchItems(items)),
    }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

I  used to have a component in charge of fetching my items in the DB and load them. It was working but refactored to include the fetch as a redux action and since then, it is not working anymore.

Please let me know if you have any tips.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Tells me: A <Router> may have only one child element
which I believe is because I wrap this component (App) in <BrowserRouter> in its parent

Comment: Update your question and include the BrowserRouter code. It must have only one child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your connected component with react-router's `withRouter` function:

```
// Adding the imports just for clarity.
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { compose } from "redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

// compose-style
compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(...)
)(YourComponent);

// Without compose
withRouter(connect(...))(Your component);
```

For more information: [withRouter API](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md)

Comment: Tells me that compose and withRouter are undefined - what library is that coming from ?
I'm working with React-router-DOM

Comment: `compose` is part of Redux, `withRouter` ships with react-router-dom

Comment: It worked ! thanks guys! I was not importing the compose from the right place!
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

sn42 is right. But I prefer to export the container with `withRouter` function rather than using `compose`

```
export default withRouter((connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)));
```

Comment: This works as well indeed and might be a bit more straightforward for a beginner - I'll use that.
Thanks !